# Got error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 when trying to execute if statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not very experienced with the way sql works really but I am trying to check if the database contains a value and if so then it finds all the values to id and if not it only binds one particular value to the idea. I get the error in my error log for the line `<?php foreach ($edited as $key => $value) : ?>`

I haven't tried much to solve it because I have hit a roadblock, but I saw something talking about a binding limit and I'm not sure if I am over that limit with my first query or if I'm just overcomplicating it and there's actually a shorter way to do what I'm trying.

```
//In user.php
public function isChangeRequested($requested){
        if ($requested != "Requested"){ 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
///

<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  try {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $requestedstatus = "SELECT  change_request FROM timesheet WHERE id = :id";
    $results = $db->query($requestedstatus);
    if($user->isChangeRequested($results)){
      $isrequested = "SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE id = :id";
      $statement = $db->prepare($isrequested);
      $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
      $statement->execute();
      $edited = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 
    else {
      $notrequested = "SELECT approve_status FROM timesheet WHERE id = :id";
      $statement = $db->prepare($notrequested);//submit_day, time_in, time_out, approve_status
      $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
      $statement->execute();
      $edited = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
    exit;
}
?>

<form method="post" name="editform">
<?php foreach ($edited as $key => $value) : ?>
<label style="padding-top: 10px;" for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo ucwords(str_replace("_"," ", $key)); ?></label>
<input style="padding-top: : 10px;"  type="text" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php echo ($key === 'id' ? 'readonly' : null);?> <?php echo ($key === 'name' ? 'readonly' : null);?> <?php echo ($key === 'submit_status' ? 'readonly' : null);?> <?php echo ($key === 'user_id' ? 'readonly' : null);?>>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<input style="margin-top:20px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Entry">
</form>
```

My expected results are if the database contains Requested than the supervisor is able to see and edit all fields, but if it is not requested then the supervisor can only see and edit the Approved field.

Comment: I think by `binding a limit` they mean `where blah... limit 2;`. What does your catch statement output?

Comment: @bassxzero my catch statement just outputs SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 and then my log outputs [20-Sep-2019 00:16:53 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/cwautomo/public_html/employee/action.php on line 69 and line 69 is the one I stated in the post

Comment: Why didn't you bind :id after $requestedstatus = "SELECT...

Comment: @nbk not sure, I was just trying to use it to get the status and then have the other querys bind the info to id if the $requestedstatus contained "Requested" or not

Comment: i understand that but without binding you can't get an answer, because it looks literary for :id.  Maybe it is only me but it sees like you can handle all in 1 select and a little ohp

Comment: @nbk I tried it and only responded with the value of requested and nothing else

Comment: @nbk I actually got it to work by binding it, I was just doing it wrong at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  try {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $requestedstatus = "SELECT  change_request FROM timesheet WHERE id = :id";
    $results = $db->prepare($requestedstatus);
    $results->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $results->execute();
    $requestedresult = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($requestedresult as $thatshitsrequested)
    echo $thatshitsrequested;
    if(!$user->isChangeRequested($thatshitsrequested)){
      $isrequested = "SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE id = :id";
      $statement = $db->prepare($isrequested);
      $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
      $statement->execute();
      $edited = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } 
    else {
      $notrequested = "SELECT approve_status FROM timesheet WHERE id = :id";
      $statement = $db->prepare($notrequested);//submit_day, time_in, time_out, approve_status
      $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
      $statement->execute();
      $edited = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If someone knows a simpler way to do it let me know, otherwise this currently works